# Child component does not re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working with two functional react components where I'm passing an `id` (the state) of a clicked item down to a child component via a prop.

**Problem**

The id does render in the child component, but when the state is updated in the parent the child component creates a new render instead of updating the previous render. So eg. the child component displays the `id` **1** and when another item is clicked the child component displays both **1** and new `id`

Parent class:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React from "react";
import TreeView from "@material-ui/lab/TreeView";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import TreeItem from "@material-ui/lab/TreeItem";
import Test from "./test";
const { useState, useCallback } = React;

export default function MyTreeItem(props) {
  const [childNodes, setChildNodes] = useState(null);
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState([]);
  const [activeItemId, setActiveItemId] = useState();

  function fetchChildNodes(id) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({
          children: [
            {
              id: "2",
              name: "Calendar"
            },
            {
              id: "3",
              name: "Settings"
            },
            {
              id: "4",
              name: "Music"
            }
          ]
        });
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

  const handleChange = (event, nodes) => {
    const expandingNodes = nodes.filter(x => !expanded.includes(x));
    setExpanded(nodes);
    if (expandingNodes[0]) {
      const childId = expandingNodes[0];
      fetchChildNodes(childId).then(result =>
        setChildNodes(
          result.children.map(node => <MyTreeItem key={node.id} {...node} />)
        )
      );
    }
  };

  const renderLabel = item => (
    <span
      onClick={event => {
        console.log(item.id);
        setActiveItemId(item.id);
        // if you want after click do expand/collapse comment this two line
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
      }}
    >
      {item.name}
    </span>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <TreeView
        defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
        defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
        expanded={expanded}
        onNodeToggle={handleChange}
      >
        {/*The node below should act as the root node for now */}
        <TreeItem nodeId={props.id} label={renderLabel(props)}>
          {childNodes || [<div key="stub" />]}
        </TreeItem>
      </TreeView>
      <Test test={activeItemId} />
    </div>
  );
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<MyTreeItem id="1" name="Applications" />, rootElement);
```

Child class:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Test({ test }) {
  return <h1>{test}</h1>;
}
```

To reproduce the problem:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-5kfbl

Comment: I am not seeing `1` displayed anywhere.  It seems to work as expected.

Comment: If you click on the `Applications` label, `1` is displayed. If you expand the `Applications`node and click on `Calendar` `2` is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Problem comes from [unexpected] recurrency - `setChildNodes` renders 'tree root' components `<MyTreeItem />` as childs, each of them with own states, handlers etc.

You can fix this by render `<TreeItem />` as childs:

```
    setChildNodes(
      result.children.map(node => <TreeItem nodeId={node.id} label={renderLabel(node)} /> )
    )
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-k8mq1

Comment: Thanks, but the only problem is that I was fetching data when the user expands a node. With this change, I can't recursively expand nodes.

Comment: You can use them recursively when children will be set/render as a tree structure of `<TreeItem/>` components - see material examples.

When you need nested custom logic ('subfetching') then you need other inter components communication method - f.e. using context to be able to send events/values to 'root' ... of course children should not be the same type .... or better context provider above 'root' (the same components type - context consumers - in the whole tree).